# Foreach inside Foreach C#

Tags: c#-4.0, foreach

Saving the value the foreach inside foreach but the inner foreach will base on the outer foreach.
All i want is to save the two data but the inner foreach will base the value of Model2.SRL of outer foreach.

```
string[] _stpr = {"\r\n"};
string[] _slr = Model1.SRL.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
string[] _chs = Model1.CHS.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
foreach(string _s in _slr)
{
   Model2.SRL = _s; // Test Value : SRL-1 // TotalCount = 5
   Model2.DTL = "Detail";
   Model2.CHS = string.empty;

   functionToSave(ref transaction);
   foreach(string _c in _chs)
   {
      Model2.SRL = _s; // will base on value from outer loop
      Model2.CHS = _c; // Test Value : CHS-1
      functionToSave(ref transaction);
   }
}
commit();
```

When executing this, the result is that the last value of inner foreach will all column in the DB if multiple items.

```
Output Result:                          
SRL = SRL-1,    CHS = CHS-1,            
SRL = SRL-2,    CHS = CHS-1,            
SRL = SRL-3,    CHS = CHS-1,            
SRL = SRL-4,    CHS = CHS-1,            
SRL = SRL-5,    CHS = CHS-1,            
Expected Result:
SRL = SRL-1,   CHS = CHS-1
SRL = SRL-2,   CHS = CHS-2
SRL = SRL-3,   CHS = CHS-3
SRL = SRL-4,   CHS = CHS-4
SRL = SRL-5,   CHS = CHS-5
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What is the current behavior?

Comment: I updated my content.

Answer (score 1):

You're focussing very much on *mechanism* rather than relying on the framework to do the *drudgery* for you.

This looks like a good use case for [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Assuming you have a `using System.Linq;` directive above this code:

```
string[] _stpr = {"\r\n"};
string[] _slr = Model1.SRL.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
string[] _chs = Model1.CHS.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
int _counter = 0;
foreach(var _s in _slr.Zip(_chs, (first,second) => new { first, second })
{
   Model2.SRL = _s.first;
   Model2.DTL = "Detail";
   Model2.CHS = _s.second;
}
commit();
```

You may be able to improve this further. E.g. you seem to have a single `Model2` instance that's reused each time through the loop. I'd have expected something like:

```
_slr.Zip(_chs, (first,second) => new WhateverModel2Is
    { SRL = first, CHS = second, DTL = "Detail" })
```

And be working with *those* instances each time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the another work around solution. @https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I just added the incremental counter per row since it was an Array.

```
string[] _stpr = {"\r\n"};
string[] _slr = Model1.SRL.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
string[] _chs = Model1.CHS.Split(_stpr, RemoveEmptyEntities);
int _counter = 0;
foreach(string _s in _slr)
{
   Model2.SRL = _s; // Test Value : SRL-1 // TotalCount = 5
   Model2.DTL = "Detail";
   Model2.CHS = _chs[_counter];
   _counter++;
}
commit();
```